# Reference request : Quotient manifold theorem for Lie groupoid action on a manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groupoids

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $M$ be a smooth manifold. Let $G\times M\rightarrow M$ be a smooth map giving a free, proper action of $G$ On $M$. Then, by quotient manifold theorem, we see that there exists a smooth structure on the quotient set $M/G$ that is well behaved.

Let $\mathcal{G}=(\mathcal{G}_1\rightrightarrows \mathcal{G}_0)$ be a Lie groupoid and $P$ be a smooth manifold.

Let $(\pi:P\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0, \mu:\mathcal{G}_1\times_{s,\mathcal{G}_0,\pi}P\rightarrow P)$ be a left action of the Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ on the manifold $P$. Further assume that the action is free and proper. Then, we expect the quotient $P/\mathcal{G}_1$ to have a smooth structure as in the case of the quotient manifold theorem. It is true, I have written down some details.

Is there any reference for validity of this result; that is, quotient manifold theorem of Lie group action on manifold extends to Lie groupoid action on manifold?

Comment: I have asked this first at MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557293/quotient-manifold-theorem-for-lie-groupoid-action-on-a-manifold It has been 4 days, there are 10 views but no response. So, asking here..